# USB-C Bridge Board Design (from USB-C to FFC)

Tags: pcb-design, usb-c

i'm working on a little bridge PCB with USB C Male for one side and EVAFLEX 5 VS connector (http://www.i-pex.com/product/evaflex-5-vs) on the other side. The target of this is to replace the USB C cable by FFC connector. The USB C side is connected to USB C Female on RealSense D435i device (3D camera), and the other side will be connected by FFC to a PCIe to USB 3.0 outputs (RX, TX and D lines).

My question is, what happens with CC lines? On the original design that FFC is USB-C to USB-A cable.

EDIT: I have broken USB-C connector of USB-C to USB A connector and I have found this:

[image]

I understand the RP function but, which is the capacitor C1 job?

EDIT 2:

I have found USB-C specification, and there is an explanation about USB-C to USB-A (page 90) (https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-type-cr-cable-and-connector-specification-revision-21). On the next tab, there is a note for A5, but nothing about B5 (VCONN), I understand I have to connect to RP too but it doesn't seem pretty obvious.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I'm seeing it correctly, it's placed across VCC and GND. So it's a decoupling capacitor. Nothing special.

About Rp and Rd resistors on CC lines, take a look at [this document](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/00001953a.pdf).

Comment: I have added a tab about Rp and USB-C to USB-A specifications, but I don't know if I should to connect VCONN (B5) to the 5.1k resistor.